How can we prove that PA has a model?
I have read that Con(PA) can be proved within ZFC (I would guess, by explicitly constructing a model of PA.) But I have also read that we do not know whether ZFC has a model or not. So, if Con(ZFC) was false, would the proof of the consistency of PA still be valid? If not, then how do we actually know that Con(PA) holds?

It’s relative consistency proof. Indeed ZFC can model standard model N of PA a la Zermelo or von Neumann, it can even model nonstandard models of PA via ultrapower or forcing constructions via its axioms including infinity, replacement and choice. If ZFC is inconsistent, Con(PA) still holds since an inconsistent system can prove any definable proposition including Con(PA) due to the principle of explosion of logic…

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://math.stackexchange.com/ See similar questions there  about Con(PA)

@JoWehler does it? Sorry, then. I'm confused because I'm not sure whether questions about logic are to be asked here or on MSE. My first question of this kind was posted there, and I was told to try and post it here.

@DoubleKnot is there some kind of "absolute truth," in logic? Sorry for the awful wording, but I don't know how to express the concept differently. Like, the truth of a proposition is always relative to some axiomatic system? After all, if a system S was inconsistent, we could prove Con(T) for another inconsistent system T in S. We could still derive a contradiction assuming T though.

@Elvis that seems another perhaps deepity question...

@DoubleKnot can you expand further?

@KristianBerry what

@JoWehler : For what it’s worth, my experience is that a lot of mathematicians tend to say that questions like these are “philosophical” (not strictly/exclusively mathematical). So I wouldn’t say it’s out of place on Philosophy SE.


"if Con(ZFC) was false, would the proof of the consistency of PA still be valid?"

Possibly yes, because existing proofs of consistency of PA require far less than Con(ZFC); notably Gentzen's proof as mentioned in the comments.

"If not, then how do we actually know that Con(PA) holds?"

We can't know that Con(PA) holds, but the consistency of PA in the sense of Hilbert (which is weaker than the sentence Con(PA) as formalized by Goedel) was recently proved by Artemov.  You can get some details at this MO question.  The existence of a model for PA within ZF of course requires much more.
With regard to infinitary entities, we can never know whether there is a model.  The existence of a model is always an assumption we make.  The assumption of the existence of a model of ZFC empirically speaking has led to helpful mathematical tools and useful consequences; therefore it is usually admitted.

Re your "The existence of a model of ZFC empirically speaking has led to helpful mathematical tools and useful consequences; therefore it is usually admitted., isn't this evidence that you're leaning towards some type of platonism implicitly due to the persistence of some commonly assumed mental models among reasonable people?...

@DoubleKnot, I am presenting Robinson's position here.  I don't think Robinson would have subscribed to such a description of his views.  Specifically in the context of models of ZFC: personally I think that it is easier to understand how Hrbacek and Nelson found infinitesimals and infinite numbers in R, from a Formalist than from a Platonist position.  Indeed, a Platonist presumably believes that he has a detailed understanding of R as handed down to him by "the great triumvirate" (Boyer on Cantor,Dedekind,Weierstrass), and would balk at the idea that there are things there he hadn't noticed.

As far as I know, the short answer is that we can’t formally prove it - this is a consequence of Godel’s incompleteness theorems. You can have a theory T which proves consistency of PA, but how do you know T is consistent? Well, you could prove consistency of T within some stronger theory T2; but how do you know T2 is consistent? It’s a situation of “infinite regress” that never fully resolves consistency questions by formal proof.
Confidence (or lack thereof) in the consistency of PA comes down to (I think) whether we think we have some non-formalized (or at least not fully formalizable) reasoning by which we can define a model of PA. I think most people would say we do have such a process of reasoning, namely that we can know what the ordinary counting numbers are and that they satisfy the PA axioms. See for example this answer on Math Overflow or the comment by Monroe Eskew to this other answer to the same question.

(1) you discuss consistency which has to do with theories whereas the quesion concerns the existence of models, not theories. (2) Artemov proved the consistency of PA expressed as CON^S(PA) within PA, so there is not necessarily "infinite regress".  (3) The "ordinary counting numbers" is something that we have pretty good intuition for, but they are numbers at the metalanguage level, not the object-language level.  They don't tell us much about models.

@MikhailKatz : Regarding your point #2, wouldn’t such a proof (PA proving its own consistency) be impossible, per Godel incompleteness?

@MikhailKatz : Ah, I found the Artemov paper on Arxiv. I see he mentions the Godel incompleteness issue. I haven’t tried to read the whole thing yet. But unless he claims to have disproven Godel, then the conclusions of the paper must depend on adopting a different definition of what “formal proof” means?

No, the conclusions of the paper depend on adopting a different formalisation of consistency: one following Hilbert rather than one following Goedel.

@MikhailKatz : Huh, interesting. Seems a bit over my head (but good motivation to learn more about proof theory). The paper’s fairly recent—does this mean textbooks need to start being changed to no longer say that sufficiently strong formal theories can’t prove their own consistency? Or is the Godel conception of consistency still entrenched as the “orthodox” one? Also, has a similar “proof of own consistency” been attempted for ZFC?

I think the answer is affirmative to both questions :-)

@MikhailKatz : Has an analogous attempt been made for ZFC proving its own consistency?

Not yet, as far as I know.  Artemov mentions this avenue of research in his article.

@MikhailKatz : I was searching for related questions/answers on Math StackExchange, and I came across this answer (and associated comment) by you in which you seem to be making roughly the same argument as I did in my answer here about infinite regress and the unprovability of consistency. Wondering what led to your change of views on this—was it mainly Artemov’s paper?

I just re-read that answer and found nothing about any "infinite regress".

@MikhailKatz : Your comment below the answer ends with the sentence “Thus, trying to attain consistency would get us into infinite regress.”

At the level of set theory, there is so far no analog of Artemov's result (as far as I know). Furthermore, even Artemov's result proves only the consistency of PA within PA.  Some people think PA is already going to far as far as foundational assumptions go :-)
